# ID with Year formatting in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm working on a contract database in PostgreSQL. One column in my database is the contract number/id and should be formatted *like ID/Year*. I have a column with start of contract date from which I should take the Year from.

Right now I have the ID as a Serial that auto-increments but without the Year part.

```
I have
ID       |   DATE_FROM
----------------------- 
1        |   2016-10-01
2        |   2016-11-01
3        |   2017-01-01


I need
ID       |   DATE_FROM
----------------------- 
1/2016   |   2016-10-01
2/2016   |   2016-11-01
1/2017   |   2017-01-01
```

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I don't know how to do it but I'm sure there is a way to do it in PostgreSQL only and I will be glad if anyone could help.

Comment: Try not to worry about formatting in the DB. Worry about the logical structure of the data. let the application format the data when it retrieves it.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the field name `"FROM"` other wise you will confuse the keyword `FROM`

```
 SELECT ID::text || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "FROM"),
        "FROM"
 FROM yourTable;
```

EDIT: For restart the counter by year you use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "FROM")
                           ORDER BY "ID")::text || 
        '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "FROM"),
        "FROM"
 FROM yourTable;
```

I assume the ID are in chronological order, other wise you can change the partition order to `ORDER BY "FROM"`

Comment: It seems the OP wants to restart the sequence at each year.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I add another query for that case.